# Installation of an application cannot be performed in MDM

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

It is MDM using APNs. 
An addition and deletion of an application are permitted in the composition profile. 
iPhone of iOS5 is used. 
It does not succeed, although installation of the "free application" of "iTunesStore" is performed by the following method by MDM of iOS. 
Has it made a mistake in this method? 
Please teach me the right method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <plist version="1.0">
       <dict>
          <key>CommandUUID</key>
          <string>995761bc0ac0f311452f050a3e4be157ca2dda75</string>
          <key>Command</key>
          <dict>
             <key>RequestType</key>
             <string>InstallApplication</string>
             <key>iTunesStoreID</key>
             <number>338761996</number>
             <key>ManagementFlags</key>
             <integer>1</integer>
          </dict>
       </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: Did the MDM profile installed on the device explicitly allow the installation of apps? What does the managed device's console show when you attempt to push an app (you can see the console using the iPhone Configuration Utility)?

Comment: Thank you. 
rlandster. 
Yes. 
I have permitted an addition and deletion of application. 
It is ending with a setting in a MDM composition profile. 
An error is not displayed in an iPhone configuration utility. 
However, there is no log which executed the command of InstallApplication. 
Moreover, the contents PUT to a server are NULL. 
Are some insufficient by setup in anything?

Comment: When you notify the managed device to check-in via an APNS notification, you should see your device checking-in via the iPCU and your MDM server should then see the device checking-in. If you do *not* see these things, then this is not an issue with *which* command you are sending, but rather, with the APNS system.

Comment: Thank you. rlandster.
Check-in was successful. 
MessageType was received by TokenUpdate and has acquired the value of PushMagic, Token, Topic, UDID, and UnlockToken normally.
then, the command of MDM to InstallApplication -- the application of an enterprise -- installation was successful.
Installation of the free application of AppStore has gone wrong by the command of MDM to InstallApplication.
No error is returned at the time of installation failure.
This is the hindrance of cause investigation.
If it carries out, how does it solve? 

Please help me.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved , i am running into the same problem

Answer (score 7):

Replace the **number** tag to **integer**.

i.e.,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
         <dict>
              <key>CommandUUID</key>
              <string>4424F929-BDD2-4D44-B518-393C0DABD56A</string>
              <key>Command</key>
                   <dict>
                        <key>RequestType</key>
                        <string>InstallApplication</string>
                        <key>iTunesStoreID</key>
                        <integer>464656389</integer>
                        <key>ManagementFlags</key>
                        <integer>4</integer>
                   </dict>
         </dict>
    </plist>
```

This problem took me a week until I **accidentally** figure this out.

Comment: Seemed to have realized that, number maps to rela or integer tags , thanks

Comment: Thanks! Its working fine for me when I changed to integer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but just found a solution ,  is the issue , when i looked into man page i see CFNumber is mapped to  or , once changed it too real it worked like a charm 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html

Answer (score 0):

For installing an enterprise IPA, you can use the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST      1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CommandUUID</key>
        <string>4424F929-BDD2-4D44-B518-393C0DABD56A</string>
        <key>Command</key>
            <dict>
              <key>RequestType</key>
              <string>InstallApplication</string>
              <key>ManifestURL</key>
              <string>https://company.com/manifest.plist</string>
              <key>ManagementFlags</key>
              <integer>4</integer>
             </dict>
     </dict>
</plist>
```

Below is a sample manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
     <key>items</key>
     <array>
     <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software-package</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>https://companyName/filename.ipa</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>com.company.appname</string>
            <key>bundle-version</key>
            <string>3</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>appname</string>
        </dict>
      </dict>
   </array>
 </dict>
 </plist>
```