# How to send a dictionary while installing an iOS app?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, mdm

As discussed in the question below, the user is asking about issue in sending management flag while installing an application using MDM.
[Installation of an application cannot be performed in MDM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802357/installation-of-an-application-cannot-be-performed-in-mdm?rq=1)
I am using Apple's Profile Manager on Mavericks Server as MDM and I can successfully install the application using it.

a) I want to know that how can you send some custom information while installing the application ? (Like mentioned in WWDC 2013, session 301, from 34:15 to 34:58).

b) I want to send some information along when I am installing the application using MDM (Profile Manager in this case), how can I do that ? We cannot pull this information from server because the app doesn't knows how to connect to the server(app is not configured).

c) In above referenced question, how do we exactly use the mentioned file and receive the "ManagementFlags" in iOS programmatically ?
Apple's Managed App configuration is out of question because that is iOS7 only, and we are supporting lower versions also.

Thanks in advance.