# iOS MDM : Is there any way to install uninstall applicatoin on device through MDM server?

Tags: ios, mdm

I am done with MDM implementation for iOS devices. I want to blacklist/whitelist, install/uninstall applications on devices from MDM server.

I have gone through the InstallApplication and RemoveApplication requests in MDM protocol reference document.

Can anyone give me sample of how to post the request in plist format for InstallApplication and RemoveApplication?

Also, is there any way to block and allow applications through MDM server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is example of InstallApplication (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802357/installation-of-an-application-cannot-be-performed-in-mdm)).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
          <key>CommandUUID</key>
          <string>4424F929-BDD2-4D44-B518-393C0DABD56A</string>
          <key>Command</key>
               <dict>
                    <key>RequestType</key>
                    <string>InstallApplication</string>
                    <key>iTunesStoreID</key>
                    <integer>464656389</integer>
                    <key>ManagementFlags</key>
                    <integer>4</integer>
               </dict>
     </dict>
</plist>
```

Here is example of RemoveApplication

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
          <key>CommandUUID</key>
          <string>4424F929-BDD2-4D44-B518-393C0DABD56A</string>
          <key>Command</key>
               <dict>
                    <key>RequestType</key>
                    <string>RemoveApplication</string>
                    <key>Identifier</key>
                    <string>com.test.test</string>
               </dict>
     </dict>
</plist>
```

There is no functionality to whitelist and blacklist apps. However, you can query device for list of application and if you see some blacklisted application you can do some actions.

Comment: An add-on on the whitelist/blacklist is that it is possible to turn off certain system applications (such as Safari and Camera) through the use of restrictions.  See the Configuration Profile Reference's Restrictions payload for more information.  If your reason for whitelisting/blacklisting is to prevent data movement from your apps to other apps, look at Managed Open In.

Comment: Thanks for valuable replies..!

Comment: Hi, Can we send multiple application list to install/remove at a time in single plist?

In MDM protocol reference I have read that we can send "exactly one of the following fields: Identifier, iTunesStoreID, or ManifestURL
value."

Comment: InstallApplication and RemoveApplication supports installation/uninstallation of only one app. However, you can have a queue of commands and device will be polling your server and getting unsent commands until it will exhaust the queue.

Comment: Thanks Victor.. Yes that is one of the solution to install/uninstall multiple applications.