# When trying to Install application remotely into an iPhone through mdm .mobileconfig file, returns "invalid profile" error

Tags: ios, plist, mdm

When i tried to install application remotely into an iPhone using the .mobileconfig file as mentioned in the question
[stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802357/installation-of-an-application-cannot-be-performed-in-mdm)

it returns an error "invalid profile".
The code i used is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
          <key>CommandUUID</key>
          <string>4424F929-BDD2-4D44-B518-393C0DABD56A</string>
          <key>Command</key>
               <dict>
                    <key>RequestType</key>
                    <string>InstallApplication</string>
                    <key>iTunesStoreID</key>
                    <integer>464656389</integer>
                    <key>ManagementFlags</key>
                    <integer>4</integer>
               </dict>
     </dict>
</plist>
```

Also please tell me what 
is string tag used for . I'm new to MDM.

Answer (score 0):

In your profile, there was no space between `"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"`,  `"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
      <dict>
          <key>CommandUUID</key>
          <string>4424F929-BDD2-4D44-B518-393C0DABD56A</string>
          <key>Command</key>
               <dict>
                    <key>RequestType</key>
                    <string>InstallApplication</string>
                    <key>iTunesStoreID</key>
                    <integer>464656389</integer>
                    <key>ManagementFlags</key>
                    <integer>4</integer>
               </dict>
     </dict>
</plist>
```

It will work.

***what is string tag used for ?***

> ```
> <string>  UTF-8 encoded string
> <real>, <integer> Decimal string
> <true/> or <false/>   No data (tag only)
> <date>    ISO 8601 formatted string
> <data>    Base64 encoded data
> <array>   Can contain any number of child elements
> An empty array may be represented as <array/>
> <dict>    Alternating <key> tags and plist element tags
> ```

String tag will be used if you want to use UTF8 encoded string in your PList.

Comment: Nop it doesn't works.Should i add something related to phone (UUID, or apple id ) ? It still says 'invalid profile'